# psycopg2: execute insert statement without fetching all data back

Tags: python, database, psycopg2

After connecting to a database, I execute a query which will return too many rows so I fetch only 100000 rows at a time. I calculate some values from the fetched data and want to insert them into another table. Can I use the cursor for the former select statement? Will I be able to fetch remaining rows in next run of the loop?

```
cur.execute("select * from readtable")
total_rows = 0
while True:
    rows = cur.fetchmany(100000)
    total_rows += len(rows)
    if len(rows) == 0:
        break

    for row in rows:
        newdata = getnewdata(row)    
        cur.execute("insert into writetable new data")
cur.close()
```